# how to install python3-tk in centos?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, centos

I need to install python3-tk in order to use matplotlib.

```
I have tried: 

(python_3.4_numerical) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 ~]$ sudo yum install python3-tk
[sudo] password for lpuggini: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.clouvider.net
 * epel: epel.check-update.co.uk
 * extras: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
 * updates: mirrors.clouvider.net
No package python3-tk available.
Error: Nothing to do
(python_3.4_numerical) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 ~]$
```

but it is not working.

How can I fix it?

EDIT:
Installing from pip does not work:

```
(python_3.4_numerical) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 ~]$ pip install pygtk
Collecting pygtk
  Using cached pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ********************************************************************
    * Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
    * To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
    ********************************************************************

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-nzjsuhx3/pygtk/
(python_3.4_numerical) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 ~]$
```

Comment: install python-pip for your python 3.4 install and use that.

Comment: I have already tried to isntall from pip but it does not work. What is the right command?

Comment: most Linux has tk installed with Python so you don't have to install. Did you check `import tkinter` in Python ?

Answer (score 22):

tkinter is available in coreos as `tkinter` package. You can install it with

```
sudo yum install tkinter
```

Once it is done, you can import and use it as usual.

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter._test()
```

For Python 3, you can install it with

```
sudo yum install python3-tkinter
```

As some users mentioned, it is available as `python36u-tkinter` or `python34-tkinter` depending on OS.

```
sudo yum install python34-tkinter
sudo yum install python36u-tkinter
```

Comment: how come when I try the script for Python it throws out an error? No package python3-tkinter available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Which version of OS are you using?

Comment: I'm on RedHat 7.4, and `sudo yum install python3-tkinter` returns `No package python3-tkinter available.`

Comment: Which is the default python version on it? Are `python34-tkinter`, `python36u-tkinter` packages available?

Answer (score 6):

In Centos 7 you can use:

```
yum install python36-tkinter
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem using these two commands 100%

```
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum -y install python36u-tkinter
```

Answer (score 3):

Or, maybe you are using [software collections (SCL)](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-python36/), then install the proper tkinter.

search tkinter:
`yum search tkinter`
install proper tkinter such as
`yum install rh-python36-python-tkinter`

Depending on which repository you are using for python, you have different "default" tkinter.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command.

```
sudo yum install python3-tkinter
```

Now Test in your terminal:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter._test()
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe tk come with python by default. If so, have you look to reinstall your python 3.4. (I prefer ver3.5). Procedures are mentioned in this [website](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4#python-installation-procedure-from-source).

Steps:

1. Download python version

   wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.3/Python-3.5.3.tar.xz
2. Install decoding tool if you don't have: `sudo yum install xz-libs`
3. Decode the xz encodeing `xz -d Python-3.5.3.tar.xz`
4. Uncompress the decoded file `tar -xvf Python-3.5.3.tar`
5. Move the desired directory to install python `cd Python-3.5.3`
6. Configure python file `./configure`
7. Build using `make`
8. Install using `make altinstall`
9. Check if tkinter works. A tk window should pop out. Open a terminal and type the following:

`python3.5
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()`

The website also has other instructions for installing `setuptools` and `pip` which are very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I spent lots of time on this problem, here is my solution effectively:

1. `yum -y install tkinter tcl-devel tk-devel`
2. to your python directory:
   `vim ......./Python3.5.1/Modules/Setup.dist`

Remove comments from these lines:

```
_tkinter _tkinter.c tkappinit.c -DWITH_APPINIT \

-L/usr/local/lib \

-I/usr/local/include \

-ltk8.5 -ltcl8.5 \ # default is 8.2 and you should change it to the version you installed in step1

-lX11
```

3.

```
./configure
make && make install
```

**Result:**

```
[root@localhost Python-3.5.1]# python3
Python 3.5.1 (default, Jun 19 2017, 22:43:42) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your python version. For python 3.4 it's `sudo yum install python34-tkinter`

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the other solutions here and none of them work for me.
After a bit of research, I found the right package that worked for me.

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install rh-python36-python-tkinter
```

if you use a different version of python3 try searching for your package as I did with

```
sudo yum search tkinter
```

and see what option fits your version

Answer (score 0):

for python 3.9 version and on RHEL:

```
$ sudo yum install python39-tkinter
```