# install python3-tk on python3.5 or higher

Tags: python-3.5, ubuntu-16.04

When I try to install python3-tk for python3.5 on ubuntu 16.04 I get the following error, what should I do?

python3-tk : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is to be installed

Answer (score 0):

`python3-tk` does not have any problem with Python 3.5 or higher, you may have an outdated source list.

sudo apt-get update

you may check if is not your source list is outdated or not, use the following link to update your source list

`https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/`

Answer (score 0):

rasekh,
I'd add that if you're on Ubuntu, after doing apt-get update, just install by issuing

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

That is basically what happens in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588444/how-to-install-python3-tk-in-centos) -albeit for Centos-. Good luck