# How do I install tkinter on RedHat?

Tags: python, tkinter, redhat

I am trying to install tkinter on Redhat 7.7. I have tried every combination if "sudo yum install [whatever]" and every single time it comes up with "No package [whatever] available".

```
pip install tkinter
pip3 install tkinter
sudo yum install python3-tkinter
sudo yum install tkinter
sudo yum install python36-tkinter
sudo yum -y install python36u-tkinter
sudo yum -y install python36-tkinter
sudo yum install tkinter
sudo yum install python36-tkinter
sudo yum install python35-tkinter.x86_64
```

...etc

I have tried to find what repository I might need to enable but RedHat support is all behind a pay wall. What repository do I need to enable?

At this point I am actually considering just switching to Ubuntu as RedHat is giving me all sorts of problems.

EDIT: I tried `yum search tkinter` and got the following:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription- 
manager
Repo rhel-7-workstation-rpms forced skip_if_unavailable=True due to: 
/etc/pki/entitlement/4690243650278863397-key.pem
====================== Matched:tkinter==========================
python3.x86_64 : Interpreter of the Python programming language
```

I already have python3 installed. I don't know if had I installed via `sudo yum install python3.x86_64` vs `sudo yum install python3` I would have got different results.

Comment: Try yum search tkinter, see if anything comes up. Also, you may want to think about using Centos 7 rather than Redhat 7 if you don't want support from Redhat. Centos is made from Redhat sources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to install python3-tk in centos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588444/how-to-install-python3-tk-in-centos)

Comment: maybe first use `search` instead of `install` - ie. `pip search tkinter` ?

Comment: did you check first if you can `import tkinter` in Python? Usually python is preinstalled with tkinter and maybe only Linux on server may not have it because server doesn't use X windows so it can't display also tkinter windows. On Linux Mint or Ubuntu Desktop I don't have to install tkinter but on Ubuntu Server probably I had to install `apt install python-tk` but first I had to install X windows to have GUI.

Comment: @stovfl I looked at that and the accepted solution was of no help in my situation.

@furas I tried that initially as I was running an application dependent on tkinter but it could not find the module. `pip search tkinter` gives some results that are tkinter-dependent packages but as I recall tkinter is not a pip package.

@Ian I ran `yum search tkinter`, see edit to original. Thanks also for the Centos suggestion... may have to look into that.

Comment: Did you try adding EPEL repository and searching tkinter?

Answer (score 5):

This works for me!

```
sudo yum search tkinter 
sudo yum install python3-tkinter.x86_64
```

Comment: My `yum` search only returned the entire python3 package. Reinstalling it didn't help.

Comment: Hi @fred, you can directly jump on the second line to for installing the python3-tkinter

Comment: For me, no such package exists.

Comment: Finally figured it out. I'm on RHEL 7 and I had to enable the optional RPMs repo. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843159/623541

Comment: Great! that' a lot of work!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I managed to fix this to my satisfaction. What I did is outlined [here](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html).  First I installed ActiveState's [ActiveTcl 8.5](https://www.activestate.com/products/activetcl/), then rebuilt python 3.6 manually by downloading the [source](https://www.python.org/) using the following:

```
$: ./configure --with-tcltk-includes='-I/opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/include' 
--with-tcltk-libs='/opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/lib/libtcl8.5.so /opt/ActiveTcl- 
8.6/lib/libtk8.5.so'

$: make

$: make install
```

Because I had a couple different versions of Python 3.x, I had to add the following to the `.bashrc`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python36.zip:/usr/local/lib/python3.6:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages
```

One big issue I ran into was first manually installing Python 3.8 (which came out yesterday) for which there seems to be little support for most packages so far, so be advised. I also had a few system-specific issues with pip.